# Security-concerns about Django email-host-data in settings.py

Tags: django, sendmail

I've set up my e-mail settings for my Gmail-account like it's described in the django-documentation:

**settings.py:**

```
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
  EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
  EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
  EMAIL_PORT = 587
  EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
  EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

So, maybe I'm to concerned about this, but I have some doubts due security while writing this kind of sensitve data into my settings.py-file.

So, is there a more secure way to set that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is providing sensitive data like this via environment variables. You can manually set environment variables or via `.env` files. There are many python packages for setting environment variables ([like this](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv)) from `env` files. Then get these variables using `os.environ`.

For example you set `EMAIL_HOST_USER` environment variable and you can define in settings like this.

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
```